# NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I am getting null pointer excaption in Test class in below Lines
Class.CasepopulateDefault.Redirect: line 14, column 1
Class.CasepopulateDefaultTest.defaultcase: line 22, column 1

PLs let me know what is missing

```
 @istest
public class CasepopulateDefaultTest {

static testmethod void defaultcase(){

    List<case> caseListForSC = TestDataFactory.createCase_SelfService(1,'General');
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(caseListForSC[0]);

    string recordtypeId = '';
    recordtype recordtypeInst = [select Id from recordtype where developername = 'Technical_Support' and sobjecttype = 'Case'];
    recordtypeId = recordtypeInst.Id;
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('RecordType',recordtypeId);

    // Set up User
    String ProfileId = [select Id from profile where Name = 'Pearson Sales User OneCRM'].Id;
    List<User> ULst = TestDataFactory.createUser(ProfileId);
    user u = ULst[0];

    System.runAs(u) {
        CasepopulateDefault CaseDefaultInst = new CasepopulateDefault(sc);
        CaseDefaultInst.Redirect();
    }

    ULst[1].Line_of_Business__c = 'Professional';

    System.runAs(ULst[1]) {
        CasepopulateDefault CaseDefaultInst = new CasepopulateDefault(sc);
        CaseDefaultInst.Redirect();
    }

    ULst[2].Line_of_Business__c = '';

    System.runAs(ULst[2]) {
        CasepopulateDefault CaseDefaultInst = new CasepopulateDefault(sc);
        CaseDefaultInst.Redirect();
    }
    ULst[3].Line_of_Business__c = 'Higher Ed';
      System.runAs(ULst[3]) {
        CasepopulateDefault CaseDefaultInst = new CasepopulateDefault(sc);
        CaseDefaultInst.Redirect();
    }

}}
```

please find below class

```
public class CasepopulateDefault{

    public CasepopulateDefault(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}

    public pagereference Redirect()
    {
        PageReference pageRef;
        //To get the logged in userId and line of business value
        User u = [select Id, username, Line_of_Business__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

        //read BV from cust setting
        string busVer;
         if(u.Line_of_Business__c !=null) {
             busVer=CS_user_BV_Map__c.getInstance(u.Line_of_Business__c).BV_Value__c;
           }
        //string busVer='Higher Education';
        //case
        Map<String,String> parMap = Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters();
        //  System.debug('parMap'+parMap);
        String id= parMap.get('RecordType');
        System.debug('id of '+id);
        //  Query the Tech Support Record Type Id
        string recTypeID=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('RecordType');



        recordtype recordtypeInst = [select Id,Name  from recordtype where ID=:recTypeID and sobjecttype = 'Case'];


        if(recordtypeInst.Name=='Technical Support' && busVer !=null ) {
             pageRef = new PageReference('/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo&RecordType='+recTypeID+'&ent=Case&00Nb000000AGUYm='+ busVer+ '&nooverride=1');

        }

        else {
             pageRef = new PageReference('/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo&RecordType='+recTypeID+'&ent=Case&nooverride=1');

        }
              pageRef.setRedirect(True);
        return pageRef;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you post your apex class also?

Comment: Yes @Reshma added

Answer (score 4):

Below line:
`busVer=CS_user_BV_Map__c.getInstance(u.Line_of_Business__c).BV_Value__c;` is accessing a custom setting record which you haven't defined in your test class. That is why you're getting a null pointer exception.

The workaround for this could be to create a custom setting record in your test class and then test it. This a standard practice to setup data for your controller and then test it.

Comment: I tried adding if(CS_user_BV_Map__c.getInstance(u.Line_of_Business__c).BV_Value__c != null) to the controller but i get the same error Rohit..

Comment: @abraham it would be better to create setup data properly. That is the proper way to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code snippet before "System.runAs(u) { "[line no.20] in CasepopulateDefaultTest class. Please put proper value to create custom setting.

```
List<CS_user_BV_Map__c> CS_user_BV_List = new List<CS_user_BV_Map__c>();

CS_user_BV_Map__c bVMap1 = new CS_user_BV_Map__c();
bVMap1.name = 'Professional';
bVMap1.Value__c  = 'your value here';
CS_user_BV_List.add(bVMap1);

CS_user_BV_Map__c bVMap2 = new CS_user_BV_Map__c();
bVMap2.name = 'Higher Ed';
bVMap2.Value__c  = 'your value here';
CS_user_BV_List.add(bVMap2);

insert CS_user_BV_List;
```

Comment: Please donot forget to put desire value in bVMap.Value__c = ''; before inserting  CS_user_BV_List

Answer (score 0):

your code fails on the profile id!
only standard profiles are available

otherwise you need the non best practice @isTest(seealldata=true) but this is NOT
the way to do it

if you need this profile to work with , the you have to create it in the test class(i wouldn't) just take standard